# Is it possible to rename view or table so that it also renamed in all serverside objects?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to "refactor" server side table or view name, so that any stored objects like views or procedures, referring this table or view, remain functionning? I.e. their code on server should be automatically edited to keep consistency?

Answer (score 0):

No. If it was possible to automatically refactor code then human developers would not be needed. But in future if you think table names might change then write your code so the table name is defined in a variable once.

```
// Define the name of the database table once
$usersTable = 'users';

$sql = " SELECT id, name FROM $usersTable; ";
$sql = " DELETE FROM $usersTable; ";
```

Now at a later date you can just change the variable...

```
$usersTable = 'members';
```